# How would "lah-teck" be pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

How do I interpret the pronunciation of "**lah-teck**"? (I am not asking for the pronunciation of *Latex*, but the specific interpretation of "lah-teck").

Comment: I think [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) show the pronunciation in phonetic symbols (two variants).

Comment: Like the rubber, or not.

Comment: @JamesPalmer “lah-teck” isn't an English word, so the guidance must come from what it refers to. Even "[An introduction to LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/about/)" is unsure about it.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that Knuth suggested that people think of the 'X' in TeX (and LaTeX) as the Greek letter chi. He wanted the name TeX to have connections to 'technical' and 'technique'.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the final consonant which is in dispute, but the first vowel.

Comment: "ah" is prounced ä, so lä. Or la as in do-ray-me-fa-so-la.  "teck" is "tek".  So I would say, la-tek. Sounds french, no?

Answer (score -1):

In your specific case, saying "LaTeX is pronounced lah-teck" is meant to clarify that:

- the A is pronounced as in bra, as opposed to the A in game, play or fat.
- the X is pronounced as ck in check, not as X in extra, flex, or xylophone.
- the E is pronounced as in check and neck, not as E in female.

It's lah-teck, not lay-teks or lat-eks. But then again, that is my interpretation of the way I would read lah-teck, and who am I to decide that this is the right way to say it?

---

English is sometimes confusing when it comes to pronunciation. After all, the G in gift is not the same as the G in giraffe, and even the I in those words doesn't quite sound the same. To explain the pronunciation of less obvious words in a written text, a common trick is to rewrite the word with a spelling that is not ambiguous. What is or isn't ambiguous depends on the flavor of English you speak and is rather subjective.

A good read on the subject is [this article](https://www.zompist.com/spell.html) by author and linguist Mark Rosenfelder.

Comment: "as in bra or flaw" - these are different vowels in my accent. I was under the impression the X should be pronounced like the ch in loch.

Comment: And *bra*, rather than *flaw*, is clearly the correct vowel for LaTeX.

Comment: Yeah, I guess "flaw" was a bad example, most accents make a significant difference between the two even if I don't. I'll remove it. But then @JamesRandom 's loch is a good example of how this is all subjective. To me, lock and loch sound exactly the same. (Note: I'm Canadian French)

Comment: English **spelling** is confusing when it comes to pronunciation. Spelling is arbitrary, like all technologies. English is no more confused in pronunciation than any other language; it's just that most others have much better writing systems.

Comment: I live in England and while admittedly Latex is of American origin, everybody here (by everybody I mean the professors and students at university) pronounces it lay-tek.

Comment: @joseph: And the creator of LaTeX told people to pronounce [however they wanted,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17509/59588) so you're not wrong. (And indeed, lots of Americans pronounce it lay-tek as well.)

Comment: Thanks! It seems the correct interpretation is "law-teck"   , not "luh-teck" as I initially presumed.